# Element UI with Electron

Tags: vue.js, electron

did anybody try to use it with Electron? I'm not able to run it.

Instead of `<el-button type="primary" @click.native="test">Primary Button</el-button>` I see just **Primary Button** text.

Probably some loader...

Here is my content: *webpack.config.js*

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue'
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|svgz)(\?.+)?$/,
      loader: 'file'
    }]
  },
  babel: {
    "presets": ["es2015"],
    "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ExternalsPlugin('commonjs', [
      'electron'
    ])
  ]
}
```

*Main.js* is easy:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Button } from 'element-ui'
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.use(Button)

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: { App }
})
```

And here is my list of dev-dependencies:

- "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1"
- "babel-core": "^6.7.4"
- "babel-loader": "^6.2.4"
- "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0"
- "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0"
- "babel-runtime": "^5.8.38"
- "css-loader": "^0.23.1"
- "electron-prebuilt": "^0.37.2"
- "file-loader": "^0.11.2"
- "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6"
- "style-loader": "^0.18.2"
- "url-loader": "^0.5.8"
- "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.3.2"
- "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.0"
- "vue-loader": "^8.2.2"
- "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0"
- "webpack": "^1.12.14"
- "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"

And dependencies:

- "element-ui": "^1.3.7"
- "jquery": "^2.2.2"
- "vue": "^1.0.19"

Thanks